# Code to output Mersenne Primes is not working

Tags: c++, xcode, primes

I am trying to output a list of Mersenne primes using the most basic possible code (I'm a total beginner to C++).  My compiler (XCode) compiles and runs it successfully, but doesn't show any result. The output window simply disappears when I run it. Could someone point out the errors in my code (without adding more things like functions/files, etc.?) If it isn't possible, could someone suggest another code? Thanks.

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  meressene
//
//  Created by Chiraag Thakur on 19/09/16.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 Chiraag Thakur. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int i, n;
    unsigned long int p, prime, a;
    for (i=2; i<=(p/2); ++i,++p) {
        if(p%i==0){
            ;}
        else if(p<1.79E+308){
            a=pow(2, p);
            prime=a-1;
            for(n=2;n<=(prime/2);++n)
                if(prime%n==0){
                    ;
                }
                else{
                    cout<<prime<<"\n";
                }
        }
    else if (p>=1.79E+308)
    {exit(0);

    }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you open a terminal and run the program from there?

Comment: You run until `p/2` but you never set `p` to a value.

Comment: Prefer to use `return 0` in `main` instead of `exit(0)`.

Comment: Using left shift is often more efficient than `pow(2,x)`.

Comment: You should prompt the User to press Enter at the end of your program.  This should keep the console window open until that Enter key is pressed.

Comment: a=pow(2, p):  You are going to run out of bits very quickly, once p exceeds the number of bits in an unsigned long int.

Comment: `p` is always less than 1.79E+308. You should read some more about integers and floating point.

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone point out the errors in my code (without adding more
>   things like functions/files, etc.?)

You're iterating `i` and `p` in the same loop:

```
for (i=2; i<=(p/2); ++i,++p) {
```

this should be a nested loop.  Rather than go until `i<=(p/2)` above or `n<=(prime/2)` below:

```
for(n=2;n<=(prime/2);++n)
```

we should stop at the square root.  But since `sqrt()` is based on doubles, we'll turn the equation around to the square instead:

```
n * n <= prime
```

Since `pow()` is also based on type `double`, we'll avoid it in this expression:

```
a=pow(2, p);
```

and use a shift `2UL << (p - 1)` instead.  I'm not sure where this limit originates:

```
p<1.79E+308
```

(Where's your code comment?) I'm going to limit the loop to the highest power of two that doesn't overflow the unsigned long integer type.  For performance, I'm going to switch to just odd numbers, not all numbers, and handle Mersenne prime 3 as a special case.  The reworked code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAXIMUM_EXPONENT (63) // OSX uses 64 bit unsigned long

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    printf("%lu\n", 3UL); // get first Mersenne prime out of the way to simplify code

    for (unsigned int number = 3; ; number += 2) {
        bool is_prime = true;

        for (unsigned int divisor = 3; divisor * divisor <= number; divisor += 2) {
            if (number % divisor == 0) {
                is_prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (is_prime) {
            if (number <= MAXIMUM_EXPONENT) {
                unsigned long int mersenne_number = (2UL << (number - 1)) - 1;
                bool is_mersenne_prime = true;

                for (unsigned long int divisor = 3; divisor * divisor <= mersenne_number; divisor += 2) {
                    if (mersenne_number % divisor == 0) {
                        is_mersenne_prime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (is_mersenne_prime) {
                    printf("%lu\n", mersenne_number);
                }

            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I used **C** instead of **C++** as the additional features of **C++**  weren't used in your original code.

**OUTPUT**

```
> ./a.out
3
7
31
127
8191
131071
524287
2147483647
2305843009213693951
>
```

Of course, this is the wrong way to go about finding Mersenne primes but you wanted to use "the most basic possible code".